# Access sqlite DB IOS

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, file

**I'm looking to access my sqlite database, be it via an application, browser or just the plain file. I can't find the file.**

Not aiming for the dumbest question of the year award here, I seriously can't find it.

Supposedly it was in `Library - Application support - Coresimulator - ....`

Core simulator doesn't exist here, so I can't continue my search.

Then supposedly it was changed to `Library - Developer - Coresimulator - Devices ....`

Devices doesn't exist here, so I can't continue my search.

Allowing search for hidden files via command: `defaults write com.apple.finder AplleShowAllFiles YES`

Still not able to locate my sqlite database file. The application in which I'm using the database works like a charm, I just simply can't access the data that is stored because I can not find the file..

It probably is as stupid as can be, but please enlighten me as to where I can find it in my release of OS X. (10.10 yosemite)

Comment: Can you please tell me Xcode version and iOS version for App?

Comment: If you have trouble on simulator, use it with real device. In Xcode 7 go to Window - Devices - Your iPhone/iPad - choose Application in your summary window and click on Settings button below installed application list and check Download container (Show container if you want to see what's there). On Xcode below 7, steps are the same as I recall.

Comment: Xcode 7, iOS 9.0.

I'm looking for the location of the file on my mac. The pathname if possible. It has to be somewhere right? ..

Comment: It has to be in Library - Developer - Coresimulator- Devices. Try this: NSLog(@"Application simulator directory: %@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]); - add this to your app delegate in didFinish... this will print out the whole directory path

Comment: There is no folder named Devices in my coresimulator folder, all there is is the folder Profiles, which leads to a folder named Runtimes, which leads scrap.

edit: command you entered was not correct. Ran update to latest swift syntax, which did something. But still not working.

Comment: NSLog printed that out? Have you tried to see whole path with code mentioned above?

Comment: Code mentioned above provides a runtime error. Code does not work. 'Build Failed' i.e. It's not printing anything.

Comment: I am using it in my project iOS 9 normally. What is the error message?

Comment: It wants to add an unlimited amount of comma's, as in if I add one the error still persists. Could you please post the complete function? It's weird that it works on one end and doesn't on the other.

Comment: Copy paste from my project (add it to your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions): NSLog(@"Simulator directory: %@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);

Comment: Thanks for your help and attention. I understand what you want me to do, but it presents an error message. It does not work. Can you please post the complete function so I can add it exactly the way that it is working for you?

Comment: Perhaps it is pasted differently as a comment here and some spacing is missing? I can not get it to work, I have tried for quite some time now.

Comment: In AppDelegate.m                                                                                           - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {     NSLog(@"Simulator directory: %@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]); }

Comment: Ah. I coded in swift, not in objective-C, should've probably mentioned. I already thought it looked a bit different then usual but figured it might've been my lack of knowledge.. I'll have a look to see if I can translate it. I'll get back to you if I do, thanks!

Comment: Right. Getting close now. This runs without error messages, however it does not return anything. Any ideas on how to complete it?: NSLog("Application simulator directory: %@", NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask))

Comment: This won't work either. I'm clueless. let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        print("Possible sqlite file: \(urls)")